# C - yesterday date

Tags: c, date

I'm building a function that given an input date in format dd/mm/yyyy returns the date of the day before.

Currently using this solution, which has multiple flaws:

- day before 1/1/2020 will be 31/0/2020, the year does not change
- every month is accounted has if it contains 31 days

also my year turns to 0 in strftime...

```
    Date dateDayBefore(char* inputDate)
    {
        struct tm dayBefore = { 0 };

        char** fields = split(inputDate, 3, "/");

        dayBefore.tm_mday = atoi(fields[0]);
        dayBefore.tm_mon = atoi(fields[1]);
        dayBefore.tm_year = atoi(fields[2]);

        dayBefore.tm_mday--;
        mktime(&dayBefore);

        char yesterday[10];
        strftime(yesterday, sizeof yesterday, "%d/%m/%Y", &dayBefore);

        return dateCreate(yesterday);
    }
```

Is there anyway to do this without having to check for every possibility?

Or just face it and start typing if's?...

Comment: You need `mktime`

Comment: I use mktime after subtracting a day. How should I use it then? @qrdl

Comment: Please show the input data.

Comment: @walkman Sorry, I didn't notice that you are using `mktime` already. So you are saying `mktime` doesn't work? BTW months are numbered from 0, not from 1, and year from 1900

Comment: @Gerhardh inputDate is guaranteed to be a date like so:  15/6/2020

Comment: Then input is wrong. You would need to provide `"15/5/120"` if you feed that numbers into `mktime` without applying offsets.

Comment: @qrdl oh months going 0 to 11 explains most of the problem and now that you mentioned it i checked the doc again and it's right in front of my nose...

Comment: @Gerhardh I can't provide such input I'll need to adjust it inside the function but then release it again as a "normal" year. Thanks

Comment: strftime keeps giving me a string without the year in it, any thoughts on that?

Comment: https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time

Comment: @abelenky priceless thanks for sharing had a good time reading it!

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to seconds (`time_t`) using `mktime()`, subtract 86400 (60 * 60 * 24), and convert it back to the format you want (I think that would be `localtime()`). You may need to study the timezone implications of this. Also you may need to solve the DST implications, either by using GMT or fudging the DST settings or subtraction value.

Note that `mktime()` will fix up maladjusted time specifications for you such as you describe (check the man page). That may be another solution.

Comment: I may not work correctly for days that have 25 or 23 hours

Comment: yeah I just realized that

Comment: what about Leap Second? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second

Comment: @tstanisl Somehow I don't get the impression the OP will be all that concerned about leap second, given the window of vulnerability. It's possible that I am wrong. Doing time calculations accurately is incredibly complex and for some applications, perfect accuracy is not needed. I will issue a disclaimer though: This solution may not be suitable for use in mission-critical or large-scale production applications.